# Configuração de limite na inserção de dados no mysql

Tags: mysql

Procura uma configuração especifica no banco de dados mysql, antigamente tinha um servidor com mysql instalado(não por mim), quando eu realizava uma query de insert/update que possuia um conteudo acima do permitido ele cortava o conteudo para o limite estabelicido na configuração da tabela, por exemplo. 
Se eu for tentar inserir '1234567890' em um campo que o limite é de 5 caracteres, ao invez de me retornar o erro de 'Data too long for column' ele corta o conteudo para o limite do capo nesse caso '12345'. Migrei de servidor e o mesmo não tem essa configuração, ele me retorna o erro acima, qual configuração deve realizar, o servidor é um CentOs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No arquivo `my.ini` deve estar como STRICT, no sql-mode:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict
- `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`

  Ative o modo SQL estrito para todos os mecanismos de armazenamento. Valores de dados inválidos são rejeitados
- `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`

  Ative o modo SQL estrito para mecanismos de armazenamento transacional e quando possível para mecanismos de armazenamento não transacional

Se desabilitar configurando `sql-mode` será permissivo, apesar de recomendar que ajuste isto na aplicação, quero dizer, ajuste para o usuário saber que passou o limite dos dados, valide as entradas de dados, porque realmente cortar um texto ou inserir uma data invalida pode ser um problema.

Comment: Valeu era essa o nome da configuração, no meu caso tive que retirar no arquivo /etc/mysql/my.cnf
Colocando a seguinte linha no arquivo
sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION sem a opção STRICT_ALL_TABLES